# Should Desktop UI Patterns include Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, patterns

Not much to describe here. But I think that it'd be a good idea to have UI-Pattern documents to suggest relevant keyboard shortcuts. However, I haven't seen it anywhere and I'm wondering whether this should be in some other documents.

So besides a yes I'd like to have some examples (links to documents or something) that outline the right use of such idea.

If it's a no, I'd like to know why.

Comment: I thought of another question related to this, and that is the use of keyboard combined with mouse. I don't normally see this covered anywhere in interaction design guides.

Answer (score 1):

Generally keyboard shortcuts would be part of the accessibility support for usability design, so I don't think it fits into any particular UI design pattern (unless you are talking about assistive technology or something like that). Generally this should be self-evident in the implementation of the user interface design (i.e. you would provide the shortcut keys next to the function or in a configuration window), or it should be documented by the developers (i.e. key bindings or mappings in the code) or in an interaction or behaviour guide.

There is something in the Microsft UI design guide:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971323.aspx

Comment: The MacOSX HCI Guideline has a keyboard shortcuts section of its own. But it doesn't deal with interaction design patterns. However, I've identified that UI Patterns tend to have keyboard (and mouse as you metnioned) interaction associated with them. Moreover, UI Patterns are commonly referred to as Interaction Design Patterns. So the question is whether ID/UI Patterns should include this to tightly integrate understanding and expected interactions. I'd assume that's the case, but haven't seen anything like it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [Keyboard Shortcuts](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/keyboard-shortcuts) design pattern at UI-Patterns.com. It includes a few examples as well.

Comment: If you can please copy and paste the relevant portions into your post.

Comment: That would go beyond "fair use", wouldn't it? Sounds like going beyond copyright infringement...